# Provide constants

Tags: angular

Provide was deprecated in RC4.

Before, I could do:

```
provide("API_URL", {useValue: "address"})
```

I'm trying something like this:

```
{
   provide: "API_URL",
   useValue: "address"
}
```

But this not working. I found few examples [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dependency-injection.html#!#provide), but there is no examples on constants.

Comment: In link you provided, there is `{ provide: TITLE,         useValue:   'Hero of the Month' }`

Comment: Not sure how you use `{
   provide: "API_URL",
   useValue: "address"
}` but it should work as well.

Comment: @estus if it was working I wouldn't write it =)

Comment: This `{ provide: "API_URL", useValue: "address" }` works as `@Inject('API_URL') private apiUrl)` injection, as of RC4.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use the `OpaqueToken` class for this:

**tokens.export.ts**

```ts
import { OpaqueToken } from '@angular/core';

export const API_URL = new OpaqueToken('API_URL');
export const OTHER_TOKEN = new OpaqueToken('OTHER_TOKEN');
```

**UPDATE** - since Angular 4.0 `OpaqueToken` is deprecated, please use [`InjectionToken`](https://angular.io/api/core/InjectionToken):

```ts
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

export const API_URL = new InjectionToken<string>('API_URL');
export const OTHER_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<string>('OTHER_TOKEN');
```

**main.ts**

```ts
{
   provide: API_URL,
   useValue: "address"
}
```

Comment: It Component I should use:
constructor(@Inject("API_URL") private apiUrl) {}

?

Comment: @Illorian `@Inject(API_URL) private apiUrl)`. `API_URL` variable should be imported. The reason for using opaque tokens is that they are unique.

Comment: Might also want to show `InjectionToken` since `OpaqueToken` is deprecated in 4+

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in my application like :

```
export class AppSettings {
    public static get API_ENDPOINT(): string { return 'http://localhost:3003'; }
}
```

Include (import the class and use the variable) it in the application where needed.

Comment: I know this solution, but i want use DI =)

Comment: Because it's variable will be using in other reps and used as submodule

Comment: @Illorian did you find a way? i'm trying to do the same thing (submodule of constants)

Comment: @omer in my case I start using enviroments

Comment: @Illorian you added global constants as env variable?

Comment: @omer I have just only one constant - server url and I'm using it only at one place.