# Application constant in angular2?

Tags: angular

I need to set application constants in my angular2 application , so that the things are available through out the entire application , in angular 1 i did with angular.constant and angular.value. I am looking for the best way here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Define global constants in Angular 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34986922/define-global-constants-in-angular-2)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/38718878/2460760

Answer (score 5, accepted):

file `constants.ts`

```
export const XXX = 'yyy';
```

`otherfile.ts`

```
import {XXX} from 'constants.ts'
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to encapsulate them in a variable:

```
export const BaseConstants = Object.freeze({
  BASE_API_URL: 'http://example.com/'
});
```